# mouse not taking input

Tags: c, bgi

I am trying to implement mouse interfecing but somethings wrong with the input function.It should tell me that wheater i have made a left click or a right click but its not printing anything.Have a look:

```
#include<graphics.h>
#include<dos.h>
union REGS in,out;
void Graphics(void);
void DetectMouse(void);
void ShowMouse(void);
void HideMouse(void);
void InputMouse(void);
int main()
{
    Graphics();
    DetectMouse();
    ShowMouse();
       //   HideMouse();
    InputMouse();
    getch();
    closegraph();
    return 0;
}
void Graphics(void)
{
    int driver=DETECT,mode;
    initgraph(&driver,&mode,"C:\\TC\\bgi");
    outtextxy(1,1,"Graphics mode activated!");
}
void DetectMouse(void)
{
    int result;
    in.x.ax=0;
    result=int86(0x33,&in,&out);
    if(result)
    {
        outtextxy(10,10,"Driver succesfully detected");
    }
    else
    {
        outtextxy(10,10,"Driver not detected");
    }
}
void ShowMouse(void)
{
    in.x.ax=1;
    int86(0x33,&in,&out);
}
void HideMouse(void)
{
    in.x.ax=2;
    int86(0x33,&in,&out);


}
void InputMouse(void)
{
    for(;kbhit();)
    {
    int x,y;
    in.x.ax=3;
    int86(0x33,&in,&out);
    if(out.x.bx==1)
        outtextxy(30,30,"Left click");
    if(out.x.bx==2)
        outtextxy(40,40,"Right click");
    if(out.x.bx==3)
        outtextxy(50,50,"Middle click");
    delay(100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `if((out.x.bx & 1) != 0) ...` - i.e. check just bit 0 - I note that many of the flags are 'unused' for INT33 AX=3 - whether this guarantees them zero or not is anyone's guess.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have a main loop. INT 33 AX=0003 doesn't block waiting for mouse input.